# way to check two lists positions and group them

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists:

```
a1 = [1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 2]
b1 = [5, 3, 2, 4, 6, 1]
```

i want now do it with positions:
like:
if a1 pos == b1 pos:

```
group1 = [6]
```

if pair 4 - 3 and 3 - 4:

```
group2 = [3, 4]
```

if pair [1, 5] and [5, 2] and [2, 1]

```
group3 = [1, 2, 5]
```

Comment: You've already done it. Congratulations. If you want it for other lists, please describe how they look in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
groups = {}
for a, b in zip(a1, b1):
    group = groups.get(a, {a}) | groups.get(b, {b})
    for x in group:
        groups[x] = group

groups = set(map(tuple, groups.values()))
# {(6,), (3, 4), (1, 2, 5)}
```

This iterates the two lists pairwise (`zip`) and keeps track of the permutation group for each element using set union (`|`). It then reduces it to the unique groups (using a `set` of `tuple` as the original sets values are not hashable)

Comment: amazing thanks now i check this line by line :D, I never use groups[a] = groups[b] = groups.get(a, set()) | groups.get(b, set()) | {a, b} with =  = = in python. :)

Comment: That is the best approach (checking line by line) ;-) just print groups after each iteration

Comment: Actually this wasn't working for group of size > 3. I added a change for that.

Comment: First i think i need look in a1[0] then check numer in b1[0] and then looking for b[0] number in a1 and group them this way, but your way is the best.

Comment: @Krzyzaku What's "best" depends on the data and what you mean with "best". This takes up to quadratic time. Practically linear time or true linear time are possible as well, though you'd need to not ignore my comment under the question.

Comment: @user2390182 - not sure you have to convert the result set to `list` -but that's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean by your latter 2 cases, and what their inputs  would look like, but for the first case you can do:

```
z = [x for x, y in zip(a1, b1) if x == y]
```